# Customize To Field in Send Email Page

Tags: visualforce, send-email

our clients have a silly need, they want to insert manually the address "To" in Send Email standard Page. 
Imagae Below 
[image]

My question is : There is a Way to hide the standard field and add a custom Text field where the customer can write  the To address manually. 
The alternative solution is building a custom Send Email Page but the effort is huge considering the Attachment and Template functionalities.

Thank  you for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can give them a custom VF page where they enter the email. Then redirect them to this page and pass the value in URL. You can't modify layout of this page.

So using this approach you don't need to recreate this complete page and your user can enter the details as needed.

Sample URL for reference

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p24='+userInfo.getuserEmail(+'&p5='+userInfo.getuserEmail()
```

Comment: It's not possible to use the EmailMessage standard controller e build a page with the standard action ?

Comment: @L.benedettini never tried that [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) to create VF page. There are many option template, attachment are missing in that. So might be not easy if doable.